# debian networking lacp throughput and redundancy

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I am encountering the following scenario:
Physical server w/ 4 NICs and 
two HP ProCurve GigabitEthernet switches in a stack

$Server runs debian (proxmox ve latest)
I'd like to configure the network as follows:
LACP (for dual-gigabit connection, more throughput) over eth0 and eth1.
another LACP over eth2 and eth3.
redundant bonding over lacp1 and lacp2 so that I can get a redundant uplink of 2Gbit. Is this even possible? Which modes do I have to use?

I am really confused with the lacp modes and can't really figure out what means exactly what :)

to visualize this, here is a diagram of what I want to do:

http://www.xup.in/dl,97816039/Bildschirmfoto_2015-07-03_um_13.53.46.png/

thanks in advance to everyone who read (and maybe answered to) this :)
cheers,
marc